# Restrict gcloud service account to specific bucket

Tags: gcloud, bucket, google-iam

I have 2 buckets, prod and staging, and I have a service account. I want to restrict this account to only have access to the staging bucket. Now I saw on https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview that this should be possible. I created a `policy.json` like this

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "role": "roles/storage.objectCreator",
      "members": "serviceAccount:staging-service-account@lalala-co.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      "condition": {
        "title": "staging bucket only",
        "expression": "resource.name.startsWith(\"projects/_/buckets/uploads-staging\")"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But when i fire `gcloud projects set-iam-policy lalala policy.json` i get:

```
The specified policy does not contain an "etag" field identifying a
specific version to replace. Changing a policy without an "etag" can
overwrite concurrent policy changes.

Replace existing policy (Y/n)?

ERROR: (gcloud.projects.set-iam-policy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Can't set conditional policy on policy type: resourcemanager_projects and id: /lalala
```

I feel like I misunderstood how roles, policies and service-accounts are related. But in any case: is it possible to restrict a service account in that way?

Comment: Be very careful using this command. If your command were permitted, you'd delete your project's current IAM configuration and replace it with this single, conditional role binding. You don't want to do this and are being correctly (albeit confusingly) denied. What you should do in this case it `gcloud projects get-iam-policy ...` save the result to a file, *include* your proposed changes and then `gcloud projects set-iam-policy ...`. I've not used conditions but I think a better alternative is to explicitly grant your service account permission to the staging bucket only.

Comment: See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam#project-level_roles_vs_bucket-level_roles

Answer (score 0):

Following comments, i was able to solve my problem. Apparently bucket-permissions are somehow special, but i was able to set a policy on the bucket that allows access for my user, using gsutil:

```
gsutils iam ch serviceAccount:staging-service-account@lalala.iam.gserviceaccount.com:objectCreator gs://lalala-uploads-staging
```

After firing this, the access is as-expected. I found it a little bit confusing that this is not reflected on the service-account policy:

```
% gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy staging-service-account@lalala.iam.gserviceaccount.com
etag: ACAB
```

Thanks everyone